# Binding TextBlock text in a new Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, showdialog

I've created a warning window to verify delete actions by the user, using Window.ShowDialog and setting the DialogResult. Everything works fine, except that the warning text doesn't appear in the `TextBlock` and I don't know why. Here's my `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="RoVCo.Windows.VerifyWindow"
        ....
        WindowStyle="None" Padding="10" ResizeMode="NoResize">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Height="Auto" Text="{Binding TBText, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Yellow" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="10,0" Width="50" Click="CancelVerify" />
                <Button Content="OK" Width="50" Click="ConfirmVerify" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the class:

```
public partial class VerifyWindow : Window
{
    public VerifyWindow(string content)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _text = content;
    }
    private string _text = "";
    public string TBText { get { return _text; } }

    private void CancelVerify(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
    private void ConfirmVerify(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And I call it like such:

```
var window = new RoVCo.Windows.VerifyWindow("Removing this skill will erase all DP spent on it from all levels. Continue?");
if (window.ShowDialog() == false) return;
```

Comment: Answer: I had to set the DataContext of the Window to itself before I can use properties from the code behind. `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` Seems to me like it should do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use binding, you need the local property to be public, and either a notifying property or a dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

1. Change your VerifyWindow constructor to:

   public VerifyWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

and remove the TBText and _text code.

1. Create a new class called VerifyViewModel

   public class VerifyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public VerifyViewModel(string content)
       {
           this.TBText = content;
       }

   ```
   public string TBText { get; private set; }

   #region INPC code - can create an abstract base view model class and put this there instead

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
       {
           handler(this, e);
       }
   }
   #endregion
   ```

   }
2. Call this code as below

   var viewmodel = 
   new VerifyViewModel ("Removing this skill will erase all DP spent on it from all levels. Continue?");

   ```
       var window = new VerifyWindow
       {
           DataContext = viewmodel
       };
       if (window.ShowDialog() == false) return;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If its just a single property that you are using in the `Dialog` I think using a `DependancyProperty` will be the better option then adding all the `INotifyPropertyChanged` logic

```
public partial class VerifyWindow : Window
{
    public VerifyWindow(string content)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TBText = content;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TBTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TBText", typeof(string), typeof(VerifyWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string TBText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TBTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TBTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private void CancelVerify(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
    private void ConfirmVerify(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```